# How to install older skype version?

Tags: skype

How to install older skype version? Group chats not working in ubuntu,but working in live, and windows current version.

Comment: group chats are 'glitchy' on Linux, especially video calling and such, and they know about the issue.  Are you talking about group voice calls or group video calls?

Comment: Older Skype versions won't work anyway, so it's not a solution to the problem.

Comment: I`m about text group chat. Funny is I have one chat open in older version and it still working. But new chats not appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Skype snap package

You don't need to install older versions of Skype anymore. Skype has finally made it into the Ubuntu Software app.  Skype has been released as a snap package.

```
snap find skype
Name      Version      Developer  Notes    Summary
skype     8.14.0.10    skype      classic  One Skype for all your devices. New features. New look. All Skype.
```

To install Skype in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install skype --classic
```

Comment: You right, Skype in Software are fine. That was old question, when there was problems with skype.

Comment: and what if you cannot run snap ?

Comment: I found these new questions that may be relevant to your comment: [Start Skype (snap installation)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003985/start-skype-snap-installation) and [Video and Audio calls are not working in skype](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003548/video-and-audio-calls-are-not-working-in-skype) (the same version as the Skype snap). If this doesn't help please post your own separate question, so we can get this problem sorted out.

Answer (score 2):

You can get older versions of Skype in the form of `.deb` files from: [here](http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/s/skype/) or [here](http://skype.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu/old)

Comment: Also: https://repo.skype.com/deb/pool/main/s/skypeforlinux; check the path mentioned in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list

Answer (score 2):

I too recently (early Oct 2018) updated my Skype in Linux Mint (17.3). After that, Skype would open showing list of contacts and chat, then a few seconds later, it would go back to the full-blue start screen, then 'reopen' showing contacts and chats, then repeat once more then simply close. No errors, just closes after a couple of tries.

I reopened Skype, quickly went to Help in the Skype menu, found the version and made a note.

I then used the second link above posted by Tshilidzi Mudau to get the PRIOR version to what I have ( http://skype.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu/old ).

I uninstalled the new 'updated' version, installed the older version from above link and Skype now works. I naturally have a 'notice' in my Skype that there is an 'update' available. I will be ignoring it.

I am yet again reminded why I do not use Microstuffed software.

Thanks for the link.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Web archive? Just select proper date here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20181117110504/https://repo.skype.com/deb/pool/main/s/skypeforlinux/