# Video and Audio calls are not working in skype

Tags: networking, skype

I am using ubuntu 16.04. I installed the latest version of skype (V. 8.14.0.10). It's working fine in text message, but when i make a video or audio call it showing me error **"Your connection is too weak. Please try again later."**. I am using high speed Ethernet connection. I tried in windows using same network connection, it's working fine.

I disabled the firewall, but nothing worked.
[image]

Comment: What speed is 'high speed' ?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue in November 2022 (almost 5 years later!), and it seems to have been resolved after I updated Skype.

Elsewhere, people write that this is a Skype bug.