# Start Skype (snap installation)

Tags: skype, snap

After I installed Skype via snap:
`snap find "skype"
sudo snap install skype --classic`
(since the old skype did crash after login)

I could not start it:

`$ skype
bash: /usr/bin/skype: No such file or directory`

How to start Skype after installing it via Snap?

Comment: Sounds like you still have the old skype installed. Consider removing it so you only have one.

Comment: I did remove it via `sudo apt-get remove skype-bin:i386` But thx for the idea. Maybe I can manually clean it up

Comment: Ah, so your shell thought Skype was still in /usr/bin. If you try in a new shell I bet it'll work.

Answer (score 4):

Try linking to `skype_skypeforlinux.desktop` that comes with the snap into `.local/share/applications`:

```
> cd ~/.local/share/applications
> ln -s /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/skype_skypeforlinux.desktop skype-snap.desktop
```

You should then see Skype in the applications list.

This should work for vanilla Ubuntu/Gnome desktop.

Comment: This helps me with my problem here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085447/uninstalled-snap-applications-still-appear-in-show-applications/1105275#1105275

Answer (score 3):

If you installed it with snap, you should run it with `snap run skype`.

Comment: That's the one.

Comment: running just `skype` should also work

Comment: Oddly enough, none of the solution seem to work. Nothing happens, and no errors. I thought snap was supposed to be an easy way. :~(

Answer (score 2):

I could run skype by typing this command in a terminal:

```
/snap/bin/skype
```

After skype started I right-clicked on the launcher-icon and clicked 'lock to launcher' which keeps the icon in the launcher and is clickable :)

Also note that you do not see the Skype icon when searching via Unity:

[image: SkypeIcon]

Comment: Yes, /snap/bin/skype is it, even on systems different from Unity.