# Uninstalled snap applications still appear in Show Applications?

Tags: gnome-shell, snap

[image]

Please notice the Skype and Telegram applications on the screenshot. (the empty icons that have the text below).

They are both snap applications and I uninstalled them both.

This is the result of "snap list" command:

```
Name                  Version    Rev   Tracking  Publisher     Notes
core                  16-2.35.4  5662  stable    canonical✓    core
gnome-3-26-1604       3.26.0     74    stable/…  canonical✓    -
gnome-characters      3.29.91    124   stable/…  canonical✓    -
gnome-logs            3.30.0     45    stable/…  canonical✓    -
gnome-system-monitor  3.30.0     57    stable/…  canonical✓    -
gtk-common-themes     0.1        701   stable    canonical✓    -
postman               6.4.4      73    stable    snapcrafters  -
vlc                   3.0.4      555   stable    videolan✓     -
```

This is the result of

> ls ~/.local/share/applications/

```
 appimagekit-botframework-emulator.desktop
 chrome-aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake-Default.desktop
 chrome-apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf-Default.desktop
 chrome-blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo-Default.desktop
 chrome-focdbmjgdonlpdknobfghplhmafpgfbp-Default.desktop
 chrome-pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia-Default.desktop
 jetbrains-phpstorm.desktop
 jetbrains-webstorm.desktop
 mimeapps.list
 mimeinfo.cache
'Studio 3T Linux-0.desktop'
 userapp-Thunderbird-LAFXMZ.desktop
```

How can I clear those icons?

Comment: Please add output of `snap list` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert: I updated my question

Comment: Please do not post screenshots with text. Post text from the terminal. Also please add text output of `ls ~/.local/share/applications/` to the question. Did you try to reboot after apps removal?

Comment: @N0rbert: yes, I did try to reboot after uninstalling apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I know how to solve this problem.

Thanks to this answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/1022504/373365

You have to go to `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications` and remove `skype_skypeforlinux.desktop` file

That's all.