# How to best install Skype on 22.04 Jammy with Snap?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, 22.04, snap, skype

how best is `Skype` installed via `snap`?

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ snap find skype
Name            Version                 Publisher    Notes  Summary
skype           8.88.0.401              skype✓       -      One Skype for all your devices. New features. New look. All Skype.
skyperious      5.3                     suurjaak     -      Skype chat history tool
audio-recorder  3.0.5+rev1432+pkg-7b07  brlin        -      A free audio-recorder for Linux (EXTREMELY BUGGY)
guvcview        2.0.6+pkg-f796          brlin        -      A simple v4l2 full-featured video grabber
spreedme        0.29.5snap1             nextcloud✓   -      Spreed.ME audio/video calls and conferences feature for the Nextcloud Snap
fakecam         2.2.0                   diddledani✪  -      Fakecam
ferdi           5.8.1                   getferdi     -      Ferdi
singlebox       23.2.1                  webcatalog   -      All-in-One Messenger
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ snap info skype
name:      skype
summary:   One Skype for all your devices. New features. New look. All Skype.
publisher: Skype✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/skype
contact:   https://www.skype.com/
license:   Proprietary
description: |
  Skype keeps the world talking. Say “hello” with an instant message, voice or video call – all for
  free. Skype is available on phones, tablets, PCs, Macs and Linux.
  
  • Video calls – Don’t just hear the cheers, see it! Get together with 1 or 49 of your friends and
  family on a video call. Watch everyone’s smiles and cries when you tell them “We’re engaged!!!"
  
  • Chat – Reach people instantly. Send messages to your friends, liven up conversations with
  emoticons and Mojis, or create a group chat to make weekend plans with up to 300 people.
  
  • Share – Do more together. Easily share your screen, photos, videos, documents, and files with
  your family and friends. Unlike email, Skype will transfer up to 300MB per file.
  
  • Voice calls – Camera shy? Make voice calls to anyone on Skype. You can also call mobile and
  landlines at low rates.
  
  Microsoft Services Agreement - https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097426
snap-id: QRDEfjn4WJYnm0FzDKwqqRZZI77awQEV
channels:
  latest/stable:     8.88.0.401  2022-09-01 (226) 147MB -
  latest/candidate:  ↑                                  
  latest/beta:       ↑                                  
  latest/edge:       ↑                                  
  insider/stable:    8.89.76.102 2022-09-06 (227) 147MB -
  insider/candidate: ↑                                  
  insider/beta:      ↑                                  
  insider/edge:      ↑                                  
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ snap run skype
error: cannot find current revision for snap skype: readlink /snap/skype/current: no such file or directory
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ uname -a
Linux mordor 5.15.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 07:51:15 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

see also:

[Start Skype (snap installation)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1003985/847449)

Comment: I thought that the "checkmark" above meant that `skype` was already installed from `snap` and that another version would be better in some regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install the Skype snap, run:

```
sudo snap install skype
```

Installation instructions for snaps are always on the [snap store URL](https://snapcraft.io/skype) after you click "Install".

Comment: that's what's already installed, though.  There's some sort of other version or something, however.

Comment: @NicholasSaunders Neither `snap find` nor `snap info` tell anything about installation status. If you want to know which snaps are installed, use `snap list` instead.

Comment: I'll take another look @mook765 -- I thought it was installed because of the check mark...

Comment: installing via snap causes some errors like freezing menus or invisible share buttons etc. i tried manuel installation, it works fine